# problem with simple calculating overtime pay on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, typeerror, calculator

> My Question is:

*Write a function that expects both a person's weekly hours worked (a float value) and their regular hourly wage (a float value). Return a person's total wage for the week (a float value), taking into account overtime.*

*Any hour worked beyond the 45th hour is considered overtime and is paid at 1.4 times the regular hourly rate. However, if a person works more than 50 hours, they are paid double the hourly rate. Thus, for a maximum of 10 hours of overtime, they will receive 1.4 times the normal rate of pay and thereafter double (2.0 times) the normal rate of pay.*

---

```
def overtime(working_hours, hourly_rate):
    if 50>= working_hours >= 40:
       return 40 * hourly_rate + ((working_hours % 40) * 1,4)
    elif 40>= working_hours:
       return working_hours * hourly_rate
    else:
       return (40 * hourly_rate) + ((working_hours % 40) * (1,4 * hourly_rate)) + ((working_hours % 50) * (hourly_rate * 2))


TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

> Can someone help me? :)

Comment: Use `.` not `,` as a float separator: `1.4` not `1,4`

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to replace `,` with `.` in your numbers i.e `1.4` and not `1,4`

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot! All the best for you :)

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer